# Cannot start nginx due to false configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config

I am deploying my django project called **"converter"** on my ubuntu machine and I am following this tutorial: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html
I have created a configuration file, which is called **converter_nginx.conf** and I have put it on the folder **/etc/nginx/sites-available**. This is the content of my configuration file:

```
# converter_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///home/andrea/File-format-converter/converter/converter.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 1myIPaddress.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste



    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/andrea/File-format-converter/converter/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

and symlinked this file as indicated on the tutorial with this command `sudo ln -s ~/home/andrea/File-format-converter/converter/converter_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.
Despite that when I start nginx I get this error: `[....] Starting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

And the `error.log` file in `/var/log/nginx` has these logs:

```
2019/10/26 09:30:02 [emerg] 30762#30762: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/converter_nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc$
2019/10/26 09:30:17 [emerg] 30818#30818: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/converter_nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc$
2019/10/26 09:38:24 [emerg] 31165#31165: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/converter_nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc$
$/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

Does anyone understand why this happens? I dont understand why nginx is looking for configurations on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and not in sites-enabled or sites-available.

Comment: its checking nginx.conf, bcs it's main configuration file which is always loaded. In that you import `sites-enabled` configs. Have u checked priviliges of that config file you created ? are you sure that file exist in `sites-enabled` ? and not in `sites-avalaible` ?

Comment: @Maielo thanks a lot for your answer! I thought that the file should not really be on sites-enabled as `sites-enabled` contains only simlinks? is that wrong?

Comment: It seems that Nginx cannot open the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/converter_nginx.conf`. As @Maielo states, you need to check the ownership and permissions of that file and/or the one it symlinks to. Did you create the symlink correctly?

Comment: Try removing `~` from `sudo ln -s ~/home/andrea/File-format-converter/converter/converter_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` as it may make the path wrong.